# Computational Expression with Generics

Tags: generics, f#

I am struggling troubleshooting this generic expression:

```
type World<'a, 'b, 'c> = World of 'a * 'b * 'c
type StateFunc<'State, 'T> = 'State -> 'T * 'State


type StateMonadBuilder<'State>() =

    // M<'T> -> M<'T>
    member b.ReturnFrom a : StateFunc<'State, 'T> = a

    // 'T -> M<'T>
    member b.Return a : StateFunc<'State, 'T> = ( fun s ->  a, s)

    // M<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> M<'U>
    member b.Bind(p : StateFunc<_, 'T>, rest : 'T -> StateFunc<_,_>) : StateFunc<'State, 'U>  = 
        (fun s ->
            let a, s' = p s
            rest a s')

    // Getter for the whole state, this type signature is because it passes along the state & returns the state
    member b.get : StateFunc<'State, _> = (fun s -> s, s)

    // Setter for the state
    member b.put (s:'State) : StateFunc<'State, _> = (fun _ -> (), s) 


let state = StateMonadBuilder<World<'a, 'b, 'c>> ()


let set1 a = state {
    let! World(_, b, c) = state.get
    do! state.put(World(a, b, c)) }


let set2 b = state {
    let! World(a, _, c) = state.get
    do! state.put(World(a, b, c))}


let testfun<'a, 'b> (one:'a) (two:'b) : StateFunc<World<'a, 'b, _>, _> = state {
    let! World(a,b,c) = state.get
    do printfn "%A" a
    do printfn "%A" b
    do printfn "%A" c
    do printfn "%A" "---------------------------"
    do! set1 one
    do! set2 two
    let! World(a,b,c) = state.get
    do printfn "%A" a
    do printfn "%A" b
    do printfn "%A" c
    do! state.put(World(a, b, c)) }


let appliedTest = testfun<int,int> 10 20
let result = appliedTest (World<int, int, int>(10, 20, 30))
```

The goal is to have a generic state monad that carries forward `World`, a tri-tuple.
The compiler reports an error for `testfun<'a, 'b> (one:'a) (two:'b)`

> error FS0670: This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable 'a could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.

Furthermore, `World<int, int, int>(10, 20, 30)` claims that the type parameters are unexpected, which is surprising me.

I suppose the problem is actually with `let state = StateMonadBuilder<World<'a, 'b, 'c>> ()`, in other words I am not supposed to initialized the state builder with a generics.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I think that what I am trying to do is prevented by the lack of higher kinded-types: http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59392

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the lack of higher kinds, it's the [value restriction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx): you can't define `state` as a generic value of type `StateMonadBuilder<World<'a,'b,'c'>>`.  Since `state` is pure, the one-line fix is to make `state` a [type function](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818987) instead:

```
let state<'a,'b,'c> = StateMonadBuilder<World<'a, 'b, 'c>> ()
```

As to the problem with `World<int,int,int>(10,20,30)` - the *type* `World` can take generic arguments, but the *union case* can't.  Since the type is fully determined by the constructor's arguments, it will be inferred if you drop the arguments, but you can also add a type annotation if you want to be sure: `(World(10,20,30) : World<int,int,int>)`

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that this `let state<'a, 'b, 'c> = StateMonadBuilder<World<'a, 'b, 'c>> ()` was possible!